# My arraylist has 3 components; int resim, int desc, int title. I want to show 2 of them in other activity. How can I do this?

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList that takes 3 elements each item.

```
public class Aciklama extends ArrayList<Parcelable> {
    String desc;
    String title;
    int resim;

    public Aciklama(String title, String desc, int resim) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.title = title;
        this.resim = resim;
    }

    // ... Getters and Setters
}
```

When I click an item in `ListView` I want to see just `resim` and `desc` part in the other activity. I have `ArrayList` named `elemanalicak` in a class named `Core`.

```
public class CategoryGoster extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    OzelAdaptor arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_goster);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_category_goster);
        arrayAdapter=new OzelAdaptor(this, elemanalicak);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(CategoryGoster.this, DetailActivity.class);
                mIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("description",  elemanalicak.get(i).getResim());
                mIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("pic", elemanalicak.get(i).getDesc());
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the place I want to show.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDetail);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDetail);
        Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (mBundle != null) {
            mImageView.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("pic"));
            mTextView.setText(mBundle.getString("description"));
        }
    }
}
```

`resim` is a pic and the `desc` is a description. How can I only send `resim` and `desc` to the `DetailActivity`?

Comment: The click is not working?

Comment: Having non-english class and variable names makes this code almost impossible to understand, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, what the objects involved are supposed to represent. Your class `Aciklama` already sounds quite broken, are you sure it *is* an array list, that does not sound right.

Comment: This is not working unfortunately.

Comment: What is not working? You can not click and cannot go to the `DetailActivity`?

Comment: Problem is : how can I send specific parameter in araylist to detailactivity

Comment: I can click and go to DetailActivity but, there is nothing to show in DetailActivity

Comment: You are already sending the specific parameter in `ArrayList` to the `DetailActivity` using `elemanalicak.get(i).getDesc()` and `elemanalicak.get(i).getReism()`.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: But this is not working. Program underlines this code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing in your `DetailActivity` is fine. You just need to pass the data properly in your `DetailActivity`. Use the following code segment instead while launching the `DetailActivity`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(CategoryGoster.this, DetailActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("description",  elemanalicak.get(i).getResim());
        mIntent.putExtra("pic", elemanalicak.get(i).getDesc());
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
});
```

Just use `putExtra`, instead of `putParcelableArrayListExtra`. `putParcelableArrayListExtra` is used for passing an array between intents.

Comment: Great to know that helped.